# Cómo saber que elementos de una lista dan un porcentaje dado o aproximado

Tags: python, lista

Quisiera saber si es que hay alguna función o alguna manera de calcular que elementos de una lista me dan un porcentaje o aproximado.
Supongamos que tengo una lista que tiene los siguientes elementos [15,10,55,43,99,88] que sumados me dan un total de 310 que es un 100%, ahora si un usuario me pide calcular un 30% o aproximado, saber que elementos de esta lista son los que representan esa cantidad.
Por ejemplo que los elementos 55 + 43 me representan un 31.61%, que en este caso son los indicies 2 y 3 de la lista.

Estoy trabajando en Python pero aún he implementado esa función

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4877/problema-con-problema-de-la-mochila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos hacer una función que reciba una lista de números y un número objetivo.
En tu caso será un 30% de la suma de la lista.

En un diccionario guardaremos las mejores listas de números que hayamos encontrado.
Cuando los números que hemos seleccionado sumen más que el valor objetivo, evitamos añadir más sumandos porque siempre me darán un valor mayor al que necesito.
Las llaves del diccionario serán la diferencia de la suma y el valor objetivo.

```py
def mas_cercano_a_objetivo(numeros: list[int], objetivo: float) -> list[int]:

    # Creamos un diccionario para almacenar la diferencia al objetivo
    # junto con los sumandos
    sumas: dict[float, list[int]] = {}
    sumas[0 - objetivo] = []

    # Iteramos sobre cada número en la lista de números
    for numero in numeros:
        # Creamos un nuevo diccionario para almacenar las sumas parciales actualizadas
        nuevas_sumas: dict[int, list[int]] = {}

        # Iteramos sobre las sumas existentes con sus respectivos sumandos
        for diferencia, sumandos in sumas.items():
            # Si ya nos hemos pasado del objetivo, no sigo sumando
            suma_previa = sum(sumandos)
            if suma_previa > objetivo:
                continue

            # Genero los dos valores necesarios para añadir al diccionario
            nueva_suma = suma_previa + numero
            nuevos_sumandos = sumandos + [numero]
            nueva_diferencia = nueva_suma - objetivo

            # Verificamos si hemos alcanzado el objetivo exacto
            if nueva_suma == objetivo:
                return nuevos_sumandos

            # Actualizamos el diccionario con las nuevas sumas y sus respectivos sumandos
            nuevas_sumas[nueva_diferencia] = nuevos_sumandos

        # Añadimos al diccionario principal los nuevos valores
        sumas.update(nuevas_sumas)

    # Encontramos la respuesta más cercana al objetivo
    respuesta = min(sumas, key=lambda diferencia: abs(diferencia))
    return sumas[respuesta]
```

Para usar esta función basta calcular el número objetivo, en tu caso 98.

```py
# Lista de números y objetivo calculado como el 30% de la suma de los números
numeros = [15, 10, 55, 43, 99, 88]
objetivo = sum(numeros) * 0.3

# Imprimimos el objetivo y los sumandos más cercanos al objetivo
print(objetivo)
sumandos = mas_cercano_a_objetivo(numeros, objetivo)
print(f"Números: {sumandos} suman {sum(sumandos) / sum(numeros)}")
```

Lo cual imprime:

```
Números: [10, 88] suman 0.3161
```

---

Esta idea evita generar todos los subconjuntos de sumandos.
Para un caso como el tuyo no notarás diferencia, pero ten en cuenta que crecerá exponencialmente con el tamaño de la lista.

Answer (score 2):

Una posible solución es calcular todas las combinaciones de los elementos de la lista, e ir sumándolos.

Vamos a utilizar la función [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) del módulo [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools

def combinaciones( inputList ):
    result = [ ]

    for L in range( len( inputList ) + 1 ):
        for subset in itertools.combinations( inputList, L ):
            result.append( subset )

    return result

def aproximado( inputList, minPercent, maxPercent ):
    p100 = sum( inputList )
    combis = combinaciones( inputList )
    result = [ ]

    for combinacion in combis:
        sub = sum( combinacion )
        subPercent = sub * 100 / p100

        if ( subPercent >= minPercent ) and ( subPercent <= maxPercent ):
            result.append( ( combinacion, subPercent, ) )

    return result

resultado = aproximado( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], 30, 70 )

for x in resultado:
    print( x[0], "->", x[1] )
```

Ese código toma la lista `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]` y busca sumar mayores al `30%` de la suma total, y al mismo tiempo menores al `70%`. Su salida es:

> (5,) -> 33.333333333333336
> (1, 4) -> 33.333333333333336
> (1, 5) -> 40.0
> (2, 3) -> 33.333333333333336
> (2, 4) -> 40.0
> (2, 5) -> 46.666666666666664
> (3, 4) -> 46.666666666666664
> (3, 5) -> 53.333333333333336
> (4, 5) -> 60.0
> (1, 2, 3) -> 40.0
> (1, 2, 4) -> 46.666666666666664
> (1, 2, 5) -> 53.333333333333336
> (1, 3, 4) -> 53.333333333333336
> (1, 3, 5) -> 60.0
> (1, 4, 5) -> 66.66666666666667
> (2, 3, 4) -> 60.0
> (2, 3, 5) -> 66.66666666666667
> (1, 2, 3, 4) -> 66.66666666666667

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho tu ayuda.